# Triangles and series

Tags: sequences-and-series, triangles

a, b, c are sides of a triangle, and are in GP loga-log2b, log2b-log3c, and log3c-loga are in AP, then prove that angle A must be obtuse

Comment: Also while asking such questions it would be better for you to show us some line of thought from your side as well.

Comment: Let $\dfrac ba=\dfrac cb=r$(say)

$\cos A=\dfrac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc}=\dfrac{r^2+r^4-1}{2r^3}$


We have $$\log\dfrac a{2b}+\log\dfrac{3c}a=2\log\dfrac{2b}{3c} $$

$$\iff\dfrac{3c}{2b}=\left(\dfrac{2b}{3c}\right)^2\iff\dfrac{3r}2=\left(\dfrac2{3r}\right)^2\iff r=\dfrac23$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

b/a = c/b 
b^2 = a * c

(log(2b) - log(3c)) - (log(a) - log(2b)) = (log(3c) - log(a)) - (log(2b) - log(3c)) 
log(2b) + log(2b) - log(3c) - log(a) = log(3c) + log(3c) - log(a) - log(2b) 
2 * log(2b) - log(3c) - log(a) = -log(2b) + 2 * log(3c) - log(a) 
3 * log(2b) = 3 * log(3c) 
log(2b) = log(3c) 
2b = 3c 
c = (2/3) * b

c = (2/3) * b 
b = (2/3) * a

a , (2/3) * a , (4/9) * a

1 , 2/3 , 4/9

(largest angle will be opposite the side with length of 1)

1^2 = (2/3)^2 + (4/9)^2 - 2 * (2/3) * (4/9) * cos(A) 
1 = 4/9 + 16/81 - (16/27) * cos(A) 
81/81 = 36/81 + 16/81 - (48/81) * cos(A) 
81 = 52 - 48 * cos(A) 
29 = -48 * cos(A) 
-29/48 = cos(A)

i.e cos(A) < 0, hence A > 90 degrees

Comment: Hi aniket. It's great to see you answering questions. I don't know if you've heard of LaTeX of not. It's a way to type Maths and for it to look beautiful. Have a look at this guide: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I have used the cosine formula to prove angle A is obtuse. Hope it helps.